# array orientation in structure

Tags: c, unions

For the union declaration below

```
union a
{
    int i;
    char ch[2];
};
union a u;
u.ch[0] = 3;
u.ch[1] = 2;
```

Since `i` and `ch` store in the same place, `i` should now be `<binary rep. of 3>` concatenated with `<binary  rep. of 2>`. However, it is stored in the reverse order.

```
printf("%d",i);
```

gives  515.
Why so??

Comment: What did you expect it to be?

Comment: you need to initialize `u.i` to 0, ie via `union a u = { 0 };` so you won't get garbage if `u` has automatic storage duration

Comment: to make it fully portable, `ch` should have type `char [sizeof (int)]` so writing to `ch` can't change the non-accessed bytes of `i` behind your back; see my comments to [Ludlin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8254740/48015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result depends on the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the machine you are trying your program on.

It is `515` on a little endian machine Intel i686:

```
$ uname -m
i686
$ ./a.out
515
```

and is `770` on a bin endian machine like Sparc:

```
$ uname -m
sun4v
$ ./a.out
770
```

This happens because the endianess will determine if `ch[0]` will be higher order byte (in big endian) or lower order byte (in little endian) of `i`.

Comment: 770 assumes a two-byte `int`. With my four-byte `int` I find 50462720. Note that the size of `int` has no impact on little endian architecture.

Comment: Is there any online emulator for running programs on either little or big endian?

Comment: @mouviciel: It should be 770 even if `sizeof(int) = 4`. You are seeing this big number because you did not clear the other 2 bytes of `i` and they hold garbage bits. Do a `u.i = 0;` before you assign `u.ch` to `u.i`.

Comment: @nikel: I'm not aware of any online ones but you can install an try the PowerPC simulator: http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Endianess is just one of many things affecting this. It all depends on how the particular compiler stores unions. There is no requirement by the C standard that the program must give a certain result.

Comment: @codaddict: `50462720 == 0x03020000`, which is the expected value on big-endian machines; as `770 == 0x0302`, you should only get it with 4-byte integers on mixed endian machines in 'reverse' PDP-order (ie two big-endian 16-bit words in little-endian order)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're printing `%d` which is for number. So, you have:

```
u.ch[0] = 3;
```

which in binary is

```
0000 0011  // 8bits, as char is 1B
```

then you have

```
u.ch[1] = 2;
```

which is

```
0000 0010 // 8bits, as char is 1B
```

And "when you put 2 and 2 together" (:D)

```
  00..00                   0000 0010          0000 0011 // sizeof (int) * 8 bits
  ^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^
//(sizeof(int)*8-16)bits   this is the 2    this is the 3
```

which is `515` in dec.

---

Sorry, I have missed the part with "why". It's platform-specific, you should read about [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and to be more specific - about Big-endian and Little-endian. There're some examples in the article. *Hint: seems like you have a little-endian machine*

Okay, I'll summarize my comment here: arrays are guaranteed to be stored in continuous memory. **Let's suppose `sizeof( int ) == 2`, for easier explanation**. So, you have

```
u.ch[0] = 3;
u.ch[1] = 2;
```

This will store first the `3`, and on the next byte, `2` will be written. SO, as you (I guess) expect, the memory is:

```
0000 0011 0000 0010
^^^^3^^^^ ^^^^2^^^^
```

BUT remember you use `union`! And you print `int`. SO, this `int` has the same bits:

```
0000 0011 0000 0010
```

AND your machines is little endian, which "translates" this to:

```
0000 0010 0000 0011 (reversed order of the bytes!)
```

Which is the binary representation of `515`

Comment: You might want to mention endianness in your answer

Comment: Yes, yes, I just did, I missed the part with "why". Thanks for the note :)

Comment: yeah,my machine is little endian.But it just implies that least significant data will be stored at the lowest address.Right??
Is there any relation between array orientation and endian ness??

Comment: What do you mean by "array orientation"? I haven't heard such thing. But arrays are guaranteed to be in continuous memory. So, in your case, this doesn't mean, that `2` is stored before `3`, they are stored in consecutive order - first `3`, then `2`. BUT, you use `union`, this is NOT `struct`, don't forget that. Suppose the `int` is 2B, as it's easier. In this case, you're memory will be as you have expected: `0000 0011 0000 0010` (`2` after `3`), BUT as you print `int`, you have little-endian machine, that's why this is "translated" to `0000 0010 0000 0011` (reversed order) , thus `515`.

Comment: Endianess is just one of many things affecting this. It all depends on how the particular compiler stores unions. There is no requirement by the C standard that the program must give a certain result.

Comment: @Lundin - Where I have said that? If this is the reason you have down-voted my answer, reread it, please.. Do you see my  "**..It's platform-specific..**" ?

Comment: What "again" ? There's just one "reversing"

Comment: @KirilKirov: I read it as "endianess is platform-specific". While this is true, there is more to this than endianess: union padding, binary representation of int and char, the size of int and char in bytes, etc etc. I downvoted because I when reading I get the impression that endianess is the only issue, and once that is sorted out, the behavior of the code would be well-defined, which isn't true.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. "platform-specific" is that whole situation, not the endianess. Endianess is one thing, that I mentioned and I haven't said, that for all little-endian machines, this will be the output for sure, because the standard says that. I know it's not true.

Comment: @Lundin - don't you agree with me?

Answer (score 0):

It gives 515 because this is *unspecified behaviour*. Nobody can answer your question without knowing what compiler you are using, and how that compiler handles unions.

- The compiler is free to store any number of padding bytes anywhere inside your union, except at the very first byte.
- The program is only required to give you back the result corresponding to the last access of the union. If your access was through the char array member, then only a read access to the char array is guaranteed to be reliable. Reading the int member can give you anything, you can't know what.
- Since this is unspecified behavior, the compiler doesn't even need to document how it will handle such accesses. If you are lucky they did.
- It is perfectly fine for the compiler to give you padding bytes or garbage values for code like this.

Comment: You're right, but @nikel does not ask about _the standard_, not even about portable code and guaranteed result. As far as I understand, the question is like - "why this is the output of this code on my machine?"

Comment: this is misleading: if the union members have the same size, the behaviour is actually well-defined (as long as no trap representations are involved); type-punning through unions is legal (explicitly mentioned in footnote 82, which was added to C99 with TC3 in 2007); unspecified behaviour only comes in because the union members have different sizes and the compiler is (as far as I can tell) free to optimize `u.ch[0] = 3; u.ch[1] = 2;` to  `u.i = 0x0203;` (assuming a little-endian architecture), thus invalidating two bytes of the integer representation; (more...)

Comment: if `ch` had type `char [sizeof (int)]`, no bytes could be invalidated and the code would be legal, but with implementation-defined behaviour (ie depending on the integer representation)

Comment: @Christoph: Said footnote also mentions that such an access can lead to a trap representation.... and then perhaps it's even UB? 6.2.6.1 §7: "When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values."

Comment: btw, TC3 omitted to change Annex J: it still lists *The value of a union member other than the last one stored into* as unspecified behaviour; in the C1x April draft, this now reads *The values of bytes that correspond to union members other than the one last stored into*, ie shared bytes of union members now have specified value

Comment: @Lundin: trap representations are implementation-defined, they can only lead to UB when used; however, common architectures do not have integer traps, so this is rarely a problem; also, re-read the part you quoted: it implies that bytes which *do* correspond to *both* members *will* have specified values; in particular, if all members are of same size, all value bytes will have well-but-implementation-defined values

Comment: @Christoph: Alright, but that is still just a draft standard. The document I'm reading from is draft WG14/N1256 ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 from September 2007, and there the change you mention has not yet been made. Anyway, the relevant document is the current ISO standard + TC:s, and neither of these mentioned drafts.

Comment: @Lundin: type-punning through unions has always been legal in C99 (again, re-read the part you quoted!); TC3 just made it explicit; the wording of Annex J is a known defect and thus was corrected with the next standard revision (which has, according to Herb Sutter, already passed its final ballot - all that's missing is the official publication, but C1x is done); it isn't that big a deal as the Annex is only informative, not normative